# Can I send a letter within the Netherlands online?

Tags: netherlands, postal-system, online-resources

Is it possible to "send" a letter to an address in the Netherlands without physically sending it? That is, using a website where you upload the letter (say, as a PDF), pay some fee, and get an confirmation of them sending your letter?

Note: Assume the address is in a form "Postbus 12345, 6789 AB CityNameHere".

Comment: It seems at least possible from France to Netherlands with the french 'lettre en ligne' which can be sent internationally. 'La Lettre en ligne permet d’envoyer tout type de courrier jusqu’à huit pages, en France comme à l’international.' https://www.laposte.fr/particulier/produits/presentation/envoyer-une-lettre-en-ligne/(language)

Comment: @audionuma: If it's sent from France, then it's not really what I'm after...

Comment: Possibly expensive but a concierge service would likely do it.

Comment: @mkennedy: The idea is to do it on the cheap...

Comment: @einpoklum I was assuming that the contents might be sensitive, thus not wanting to consign the letter to international post. In part, you're paying for privacy/security of contents.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes!**

I'm afraid that product/service recommendations are both off-topic and likely to get my answer deleted as spam, so I won't post links to any particular services. However, simply googling "[online aangetekende brief versturen](https://www.google.com/search?q=online+aangetekende+brief+versturen)" gives me a page full of services doing exactly what you want. (I've never used any of them.)